# How can I explode SQL array into separate columns?

Tags: sql, arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that has a column called "table_name" of type string and a column called "keys" of type array. I need to write an SQL procedure/queries/something that generates tables called "table_name" and each element in the "keys" column is column name. Any thoughts on how to begin this?

For example,

| table_name | keys |
| --- | --- |
| table_1 | ['A','B','C'] |
| table_2 | ['D','E'] |

would generate table_1:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |

and table_2:

| D | E |
| --- | --- |

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't you need to know/specify the data type for every column? Your table doesn't seem to include that

Comment: They will always be all strings. Couldn't I just use varchar for each one?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two steps.

1. Dynamically generate the CREATE TABLE statement form this data
2. Execute that statement.

Step 1 will look something like:

```
 SELECT 'CREATE TABLE '|| table_name || '(' || array_to_string(keys, ' INT, ') || ");" as create_table_statement
 FROM yourtable;
```

Each row outputted should contain a single column with your create table statement. Note that I made an assumption about your data types as those aren't present in your table or array.

Step 2 is up to you. Copy/paste into a client and execute or do this in a proc or outside scripting language.